Convergence almost everywhere implies convergence in measure, help with example
Consider the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. Then, consider the sequence of functions $f_n = \mathbb{1}_{[n, n+1]}$. This is how I see it (and it obviously must be incorrect since convergence $\lambda$-a.e. implies convergence in measure). Since this is pointwise convergence to 0, then it is convergent $\lambda$-a.e. However, consider $\lambda(\{|f_n| > 1/2\})$, which remains constantly 1, and thus does not tend to 0 as $n$ grows. What am I doing wrong?

Pointwise a.e. convergence only implies convergence in measure on finite measure spaces, as your example shows.

@kieransquared Thank you so much
